# How to link images to their entry in list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdftex, links

Right now I embed images like that:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images/some.pdf}
    \caption[Description in LOF, taken from~\cite{source}]{Caption for Image}
    \label{fig:sample_image}
\end{figure}
```

Using `\listoffigures` and `hyperref` this provides a nice list with every entry linked to the image position. As a requirement the source of the image has to be mentioned in the listoffigures it would be convenient to have the images or their caption linked to the matching entry so see the source without scrolling down the whole pdf.

So how do I link images to their entry in list of figures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use the `\hyperlink`, `\hypertarget` mechanism provided by `hyperref`; a little example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}    
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mycntr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\LCaption{%
  \stepcounter{mycntr}\@dblarg\@LCaption}
\def\@LCaption[#1]#2{%
  \caption[\protect\hypertarget{image\themycntr}{#1}]%
    {\hyperlink{image\themycntr}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images/some.pdf}
    \LCaption[Description in LOF, taken from~\cite{goossens93}]{Caption for Image}
    \label{fig:sample_image}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I updated my answer with an improved version of `\LCaption` suggested by egreg. This version works like the original `\caption` command with respect to a missing optional argument: calling `\LCaption{Caption}` will write "Caption" also in the list of figures; `\LCaption[Short]{Long caption}` will write "Short" in the list of figures.

Comment: This works fine for me, as there are only a few figures to add the links manually. For existing documents with some dozens of figures it might be a job for a script or a macro.

Comment: @mbx: of course, you can easily define a command: something like `\newcommand\LCaption[3][]{\caption[\protect\hypertarget{#3}{#1}]{\hyperlink{#3}{#2}}}` and then use `\LCaption[Description in LOF, taken from~\cite{goossens93}]{Caption for Image}{sample}`
 intead of `\caption` inside the `figure` environment.

Comment: @mbx: see my updated answer.

Comment: Nice piece of work, both of you. Works perfectly. Now it's really easy to add this feature even to existing papers.

Comment: Just for completeness: Just found a minor (as nearly irrelevant) drawback when using TeXnicCenter2. The object view now cannot parse the caption and uses the label name instead. Maybe other GUI editors are affected as well. Not an issue to me :-)

Comment: The location of the target seems to be suboptimal: at least with memoir the pdf viewers jump to the page number at the end of the LOF entry instead of the beginning of the entry (i.e. figure number). Still, this answer is a huge improvement for me, thanks everyone involved.

Comment: (damn too slow.) In the MWE it seems to be better, but the anchor is too low (it should be above the entry/line but is vertically in the middle of the text).

Comment: @stefanct Hard to diagnose without a MWE. You could consider opening a follow-up question; please, provide there some complete, minimal document illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: the MWE of this question has at least the second problem itself: zoom in on the caption so that the lof entry is not viewable; click the link in the caption; note that the new view does not show the whole lof entry because the top of the view pane is positioned too low (tested with acrobat 9, evince, okular, qpdfview).